# Yarn workspaces -- package alias

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, dependency-resolution

**TL;DR How can I create an alias for a local yarn workspace dependency?**

I've tried yarn workspaces before and never succeeded, and I'm giving it another try.

I've set `"workspaces": ["packages/*"]` in `package.json`.

For each package, I decided to use the naming convention `@-/package-name` to prevent naming conflicts and without worrying about having namespaces for internal packages.

When adding packages as dependencies, I've been following a style where I use an interface name for resolution, but point that towards a concrete implementation. This is what I did before using yarn workspaces:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-interface-name": "file:some/path/to/packages/some-concrete-implementation"
}
```

This is basically to allow what I like to call compile-time static dependency injection. And it also means each package can individually name their interface dependencies appropriately to their need and to prevent naming conflicts.

However, I can't figure out how to accomplish this with yarn workspaces. How do I create an alias for my yarn workspaces package `@-/some-concrete-implementation` called `my-interface-name`?

What I've already tried with no success:

- Defining the dependency like `"my-interface-name": "@-/some-concrete-implementation"}` - for some reason this causes yarn to look for `@-/some-concrete-implementation` on the npm registry instead of in the local workspace
- I've also tried to use the workspace protocol: `"my-interface-name": "workspace:@-/some-concrete-implementation"}` but it still looks for the package on the npm registry!

What I haven't yet tried and could work but removes benefits of using yarn workspaces in the first place:

- `"dependencies": {"my-interface-name": "file:../../node_modules/@-/some-concrete-implementation"}"`

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen the [`resolutions` package.json key](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/package-json#toc-resolutions)? Is it what you need?

I've used it for aliasing/overriding external packages but the example in the docs shows it working with local packages.

> #### Resolutions
>
> Allows you to override a version of a particular nested dependency. See the [Selective Versions Resolutions RFC](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/blob/master/implemented/0000-selective-versions-resolutions.md) for the full spec.

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "transitive-package-1": "0.0.29",
    "transitive-package-2": "file:./local-forks/transitive-package-2",
    "dependencies-package-1/transitive-package-3": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

From the RFC:

> "**/a" denotes all the nested dependencies a of the project.
>
> "a" is an alias for **/a (for retro-compatibility, see below, and because if it wasn't such an alias, it wouldn't mean anything as it would represent one of the non-nested project dependencies, which can't be overridden as explained below).

So, I believe the rule you need is:

```
"**/my-interface-name": "file:some/path/to/packages/some-concrete-implementation"

// OR equivalent

"my-interface-name": "file:some/path/to/packages/some-concrete-implementation"
```

I believe it works in the package's package.json. Worst case you can hoist it to the workspace root and make the rule specific to the workspace e.g. "a/b".

Comment: But it says it is for a "nested dependency". Does it also work for a dependency in the same `package.json`?

Comment: I've been told it does but I haven't tested it myself. Updated the answer with more details.

Comment: You could also look at this package: https://github.com/mweststrate/relative-deps

Comment: I used to use the `file:` protocol, but now that I'm using yarn workspaces I would like to point to a yarn workspace using `@myyarnworskpace/package`. I'll try it out anyway tomorrow.

Comment: The `resolutions` field appears to have sort of worked, but I'm not seeing the renamed package in the root node_modules folder. Anyway I'm considering switching from yarn to pnpm since they offer non-flat dependency trees, and the dependency aliases seem to work better. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Cool! Also take a look at yarn 2. It sorts out a lot of these issues. Zero install. Bunch of improvements to workspaces.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely have to get around to looking at yarn 2.

Answer (score 4):

The [workspace: alias protocol](https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols#workspace) *(available in pnpm too)* seems the direction to take.

> I've also tried to use the workspace protocol: "my-interface-name": "workspace:@-/some-concrete-implementation"} but it still looks for the package on the npm registry!

Be sure to have yarn 3 installed, otherwise you'll run into weird issues.

Note that the syntax of `"my-interface-name": "workspace:@-/some-concrete-implementation"` looks incorrect.

It should be `"@xxx/some-concrete-implementation": "workspace:*",` assuming the name of linked the package is `"name": "@xxx/some-concrete-implementation"`.

With this in mind you don't even need to create a specific `@-/name`. With workspace protocol, yarn will ensure it's never downloaded from npm. It becomes an internal workspace dependency.

PS:

---

#### Yarn 3 installation

Generally a simple `yarn set version 3.0.2 && yarn plugin import workspace-tools`) will work.

To avoid pnp current limitation, check the generated config `.yarnrc.yml` and ensure nmLinker is set to 'node-modules'

```yaml
# Yarn 2+ supports pnp or regular node_modules installs. Use node-modules one.
nodeLinker: node-modules
plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.2.cjs
```

PS: you might want to add this to `.gitignore` too

```
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
.pnp.*
```

Run a `yarn install` just after.

#### About package.json's

Like you did, the root `package.json` will define the workspace paths:

```json
{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"  // Enable package discovery in packages/* directory.
  ],
  // ... 
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "7.0.2", // Only what's needed for monorepo management
  }
```

In your app `packages/app/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "16.10.1",
    //...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // Assuming the name of packages/shared is "@your-org/some-concrete-implementation",
    // we explicitly declare the dependency on it through
    // workspace: alias (package-manager perspective)
    "@your-org/some-concrete-implementation": "workspace:*",
  }
}
```

You consumed package should declare the same name

```
{
  "name": "@your-org/some-concrete-implementation",
}
```

---

#### Bonus: Typescript aliases

If your project is written in ts, you can even replicate your paths through
[typescript path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping). It will allow to include the files just as is (no prior compilation needed).

Following your example, just edit a `./packages/xxx/tsconfig.json` in this way

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // here baseUrl is set at ./src (good practice), can
    // be set to '.'  
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      // Declare deps here (keep them in sync with what
      // you defined in the package.json)
      // PS: path are relative to baseUrl
      "@your-org/some-concrete-implementation/*": ["../../some-concrete-implementation/src/*"],
      // if you have a barrel in ui-lib 
      "@your-org/some-concrete-implementation": ["../../some-concrete-implementation/src/index"],
    }
  },
}
```

PS: for non typescript: [babel/plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) can be used in a similar manner.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my intention to name the package whatever I want, regardless of what the implementation names itself.

Comment: Ah yes you're totally right.  Context switching sometimes does this.  Hehe. I'll probably delete then